# MS EXCEL SUMIFS challenge

Tags: excel-formula, sumifs

I want to sum all cells in a row from G7 to infinity. The criteria is dates in a month in row B7 to infinity. Is this possible?

I have tried, and came up with this:

```
=SUMIFS(Sum(G:G)-sum(G1:G6);sum(B:B)-sum(B1:b6);">=01.01.2016";sum(B:B)-sum(b1-B6);"<=31.01.2016")
```

Can anyone correct me?

FYI: All the cells in row G contains formulas, but return a number

Comment: And what is the error? Also, please include sample data table in your question. Best regards,

Comment: Did my answer work for you? If so then please mark as correct by clicking the grey/green check mark by the answer. It is something only you can do.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
=SUMIFS(G7:INDEX(G:G; MATCH(1E+99;B:B));B7:INDEX(B:B; MATCH(1E+99;B:B));">=01.01.2016";B7:INDEX(B:B; MATCH(1E+99;B:B));"<=31.01.2016")
```

It will grow as the data grows.  The INDEX/MATCH finds the last cell with a number in Column B and sets that as the last cell.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use G6:**G65536** and click OK. **65536 for Excel 2003** and earlier, **1048576 for 2007 and 2010**.

For 2007-2010

```
=SUMIFS(sum(G6:G1048576),sum(B6:B1048576),">=01.01.2016",sum(B6:B1048576),"<=31.01.2016")
```

Edited: irrelevant information removed.

Comment: The `;` instead of `,` is due to local settings.  many countries use `,` to denote decimal.  In those countries Excel uses `;` as the delimiter between criteria instead of `,`.

Comment: Just an FYI it was not me that voted you down.  If you remove the line about the delimiter and the link as it is to an unrelated post on Super user this would be a good answer.